# C implementation of a minimal shell

Tags: c, shell

I wrote a program that implements a minimal shell and reads from standard input commands and executes them.

Is my implementation ok? I admit that I helped myself a lot with google. Could I have written a better implementation?

Also, I tried to check the program with the dash command, because they are similar. I tried to close the terminal with the key combination Ctrl + D, but it displays a different error and exit status. Why?

code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#define PRMTSIZ 255
#define MAXARGS 63
#define EXITCMD "exit"
int main()
{
    for (;;)
    {
        char input[PRMTSIZ + 1] = {0x0};
        char * ptr = input;
        char * args[MAXARGS + 1] = {NULL};
        int wstatus;
        printf("%s", getuid() == 0 ? "# " : "$ ");
        // get data from user
if(fgets(input, PRMTSIZ, stdin) == NULL)
        {
            close(1);
            exit(0);
        };
        if (*ptr == '\n')continue;
        const char delims[3] = " \n";
        /* get the first token */
        char * token = strtok(input, delims);
        /* walk through other tokens */
        for (int i = 0; token != NULL; i++)
        {
            args[i] = token;
            token = strtok(NULL, delims);
        }
        if (strcmp(EXITCMD, args[0]) == 0 ) return 0;
        // execute the command in child
        if (fork()==0)exit(execvp(args[0],args));
        // parent waits for child to complete before continuing
        wait(&wstatus);
        if (!WIFEXITED(wstatus)) printf("<%d>", WIFEXITED(wstatus));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

- `if (*ptr == '\n')` is very opportunistic, and leads to a serious problem. An input like    `\n` results in a segfault. You should honestly tokenize *any* input, and only then test what `args[0]` is.
- It is easy to overflow an `args` array (try `a a a ...` for more than 64 times). A tokenizing loop should hard stop at 63rd token.
- `ptr` is not really used anywhere.
- `wstatus` is better be declared where it is used:

  ```
    int wstatus;
    wait(&wstatus);
    if (!WIFEXITED(wstatus)) printf("<%d>", WIFEXITED(wstatus));
  ```
- You shall not ignore `fork` errors. As a minimum,

  ```
    switch (fork()) {
        default:
            normal_parent_code(); // Like, wait()
            break;
        case 0:
            child_code();
            break; // or exit()
        case -1:
            handle_fork_error(); // At least. print strerror
            break;
  ```
- I don't see any value in printing `WIFEXITED(wstatus)`. Much better diagnostic would be

  ```
    if (fork() == 0) {
        execvp(args[0],args);
        perror(args[0]);
    }
  ```

Comment: How can I rezolve the overflow?